# Internet Explorer - image scale on hover bleeds

Tags: html, css, scale

I have:

- A panel
- It contains an image
- A bottom container inside the image as an overlay
- Some content

When hovering over the panel, the image scales to 1.1. This works perfectly fine. However, as the image scales, it can be see quickly on the outside and under the overlay.This works seamlessly on Chrome and appears to be an issue in **Internet Explorer**.

**Question**
Is it possible to ensure the same behaviour as chrome where the image doesn't expand outside of it's own container and onto the sides / bottom of the overlay?

```css
.item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  float: left;
  background: #ebebeb;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item .content {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
  padding: 20px;
}
.item .image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  background: red;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.item .image img {
  width: 100%;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.item .border {
  width: 150%;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #fff;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item:hover .image img {
  transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1) rotate(0.1deg);
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-up-2">
    <div class="column">
      <div class="item">
        <div class="image">
           <img src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/Beautiful_Wallpaper_1080p_Full_HD.jpg"/>
          <div class="border"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="content"> Content </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom was resolved by add a -1px margin on the element below, therefore covering up the 1px gap.